# Most Efficient Way to Check Player Distance from a Line?

Tags: unity, c#

I need to get the player's distance from a line (or the outside edges of an Gameobject, if that's easier) throughout their time in the game. I need the code to be fairly simple because I'm a novice (though if it's thoroughly explained, I can implement more complex solutions).

Is there an optimal way to do this that doesn't involve resorting to using the full formula for a point to a line? Because I think I might have some trouble implementing that in unity's system (translating to/from coordinate systems, maybe).

Thanks!

Comment: `gameObject.transform.position` it gives `GameObjects`'s location in 3D space, now calculate according to your formula

Comment: There is [a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXimD.jpg) direct formula, what kind of optimization you are talking about ?

Comment: I have several lines, each of which are made up of a number of game objects (because some need to be visible at different times). I need to find the closest line to the player at each time point throughout the game.

Comment: "I think I might have some trouble implementing that in unity's system" How about trying it first, using the basic formula you can find with a Google search. It will probably work just fine for your needs — it's a very cheap calculation by game standards. If you encounter a problem, edit your question to detail exactly how you implemented it and what specific problem you found, then we can help you solve that problem.

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad for example, compare squares instead of distances, to avoid expensive square root calculations (if he wants to find minimum or maximum distance).

Comment: If you know that the line is straight vertical or horizontal, you can simply find difference between line's coordinate and the object's corresponding coordinate. Otherwise, you should use the formula that Maifee Ui Asad suggested. It can't be simplified further.

Comment: @trollingchar Do you mean pick a point on the line and compare it to the player's position? I'm trying to avoid doing that because it isn't as precise as ideal. (Though I do have a solution I can revert to that does exactly that.) I think the issue with Maifee Ui's formula is that it's the general formula for the whole line if it just keeps going (I'm trying to look at how far the player is from specific segments of those longer lines is probably the best way I can describe it... i.e. whether the player is following a particular route through a larger grid pattern.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all, because I don't have a compiler right now:

```
List<GameObject[]> gList=new List<>();//this may have some problem, try initiating in your way

GameObject[] line1=new GameObject{g1,g2,g3}; //g-n is just some gameobject
GameObject[] line2=new GameObject{g4,g5,g6,g7};


gList.add(line1);
gList.add(line2);

GameObject[] targeted=null;



foreach(GameObject[] x in gList)
{
Vector3 f=x[0].transform.position;
Vector3 l=x[x.Length-1].transform.position;

//calculate distance as you know the math
//if(condition) //depending upon min or max or what-ever
    //targeted=x;

}
```

Maybe this will help

Comment: Please explain what the code does, it doesn't help that much this way